# How to pass object as parameter to javascript using flutter_js?

Tags: javascript, flutter, flutter-js

I need to run javascript code in my Flutter project.
I use [flutter_js](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_js) for this.

I can pass **int** (or **String**) value as parameter to javascript, for example:

```
String blocJs = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/js/bloc.js");
final jsResult = jsRuntime.evaluate(blocJs + """add($firstNumber, $secondNumber)""");
```

But I need to pass **object** as parameter to javascript code.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an object in Dart and pass it to the JavaScript function as a string. Then, you can parse the string in JavaScript and use the object.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person(this.name, this.age);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'age': age,
    };
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());
}

final person = Person('John', 30);
final jsObject = 'JSON.parse(\'${person.toJson()}\')';

final jsResult = jsRuntime.evaluate(blocJs + """add($firstNumber, $secondNumber, $jsObject)""");
```

In this example, we define a `Person` class with a `name` and an `age` field. We then create an instance of this class and convert it to a JSON string using the `json.encode` method. We then pass this JSON string to the JavaScript function as a parameter.

In the JavaScript function, you can parse the JSON string using the `JSON.parse` method and use the resulting object.